# how to push notification to mobile devices in laravel using FCM

Tags: laravel-5.5

[laravel package to push notification](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM)

[click here to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY8bh.png)

[click here to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBtsX.png)